# Group by Manager Id

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below

Emp_id, Emp_user_id, Emp_Name, Emp_mgr_id

Emp_mgr_id will be the Manager's emp_id.

So for example I have data like below

```
Emp_id Emp_user_id Emp_Name Emp_mgr_id
1      D021         Joe      6
2      D024         Kathy    6
3      D054         Shaun    1
4      D058         Tippu    2
5      D059         Paul     4
6      D070         David    9
7      D075         Jack     9
```

Now I need to create a form and when David login with his id D070, I need to pull all the employees reports to David.

```
D021 Joe
 -->D054 Shaun
D024  Kathy
  -->D058   Tippu
  -->D059   Paul
```

I wanted to group the rows by his direct reports.

Anybody have any idea how to write a query to pull the data like this? Input will be Emp_User_id and output I need all the subordinates grouped by direct report.

Thanks

Comment: If you share with us the `CREATE TABLE` statement that defines your table, and show us an expected result set, it will be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the out put with CTE.But here you need to do little alteration to get display the result in the desired format.

CREATE TABLE emptbl(Emp_id int, Emp_user_id varchar(10), Emp_Name varchar(100), Emp_mgr_id int)

INSERT INTO emptbl
VALUES(1,'D021','Joe',6),
(2,'D024','Kathy',6),
(3,'D054','Shaun',1),
(4,'D058','Tippu',2),
(5,'D059','Paul',4),
(6,'D070','David',9),
(7,'D075','Jack',9)

```
SELECT * FROM emptbl

;WITH CTEEmp(Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id) As
(
SELECT Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from emptbl where Emp_user_id='D070'
UNION ALL
SELECT  et.Emp_id,et.Emp_user_id,et.Emp_Name,et.Emp_mgr_id from emptbl et inner join CTEEmp e on et.Emp_mgr_id = e.emp_id)

,CTEEmp1(Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id)As
(SELECT Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from CTEEmp where Emp_user_id<>'D070')

SELECT * FROM CTEEmp1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [recursive common-table expression](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/) for this. In fact, it's one of the most common uses for them (Manager -> Employee type hierarchies)

```
WITH Emp_CTE AS (
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_User_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Mgr_ID
FROM EmpTable
WHERE Emp_Mgr_ID IS NULL -- This assumes the top-level managers have no manager.
UNION ALL
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_User_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Mgr_ID
FROM EmpTable AS e
    INNER JOIN Emp_CTE AS cte ON cte.Emp_ID = e.Emp_Mgr_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM Emp_CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Find the sproc below to get the names in the order.

```
CREATE TABLE emptbl(Emp_id int, Emp_user_id varchar(10), Emp_Name varchar(100), Emp_mgr_id int)

INSERT INTO emptbl
VALUES(1,'D021','Joe',6),
(2,'D024','Kathy',6),
(3,'D054','Shaun',1),
(4,'D058','Tippu',2),
(5,'D059','Paul',4),
(6,'D070','David',9),
(7,'D075','Jack',9)

SELECT * FROM emptbl



CREATE Proc sp_getRepportees
@emp_id varchar(20)
As
--sp_getRepportees 'D070'
DECLARE @min int=1
DECLARE @max int

DECLARE @empout TABLE(Emp_id int, Emp_user_id varchar(10), Emp_Name varchar(100), Emp_mgr_id int)
;WITH CTEEmp(Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id) As
(
SELECT Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from emptbl where Emp_user_id=@emp_id
UNION ALL
SELECT et.Emp_id,et.Emp_user_id,et.Emp_Name,et.Emp_mgr_id from emptbl et inner join CTEEmp e on et.Emp_mgr_id = e.emp_id)

,CTE2(rno,Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id) as(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by emp_id) as rno,* FROM CTEEmp where Emp_user_id<>@emp_id)

select * into #tempe from CTE2
SELECT @max=COUNT(*) from #tempe

select * from #tempe
While(@min<=@max)
begin

IF EXISTS(select Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from #tempe where Emp_mgr_id in (select Emp_id from #tempe where rno=@min))
begin
INSERT INTO @empout
select Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from #tempe where rno=@min
union  
select Emp_id,Emp_user_id,Emp_Name,Emp_mgr_id from #tempe where Emp_mgr_id in (select Emp_id from #tempe where rno=@min)
end

delete from #tempe where rno=@min
SET @min+=1
end

select Emp_user_id,Emp_Name from @empout
```